# Cannot update a post

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits

I am trying to update an answer I just provided with some resource links - but it constantly keeps crashing on me and the kitty seems awfully busy by now :-)

Here's the question I answered:

[Is there a library to use Linq to directly query databases, dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340384/is-there-a-library-to-use-linq-to-directly-query-databases-dynamically/3340828#3340828)

I tried several times to add one or two links to relevant articles / blog posts, but no matter what I do (links inside the text or at the end of the paragraph), when I click on "save", the kitty comes up and the changes aren't saved.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed. The problem should be taken care of now.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully edited your comment. Is it only links that cause problems?

**EDIT**

Ok I see this now. I tried to edit this answer and include a link to google and I get the error message consistently

Comment: Thanks - yes, it seems to be links: I added a few lines of text, saved - works fine. Then I went back and tried to add links to those resources - BOOM! Busy Kitty again.......

Comment: @marc it appears to be every answer is now this way. Jeff broke something bad!

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into this as well on a question I created: [Can I recursively create a path in Zookeeper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340756/can-i-recursively-create-a-path-in-zookeeper)

It already has a link in it, and didn't give me a problem when I first created it. Going back to fix a typo in the code, however, gives me busykitteh.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. I've tried editing some of my older answers, and I can't, if they have links and I keep the links in.

If I remove all links from the post, I can edit it.

Kitten kaboodles!

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed that this happens on ServerFault as well, not just SO