# editing my own answers causes LOLcat error page

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, edits

Editing any of my answers tonight yields the friendly LOLcat error page when I try to save.  I can repro 100% of the time, both when repeatedly trying to save an edit on the same question, as well as across multiple questions including:

- [Which methods to close a compiled query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263052/which-methods-to-close-a-compiled-query/3332526#3332526)
- [Unable to reference UNC paths while using wscript.shell from an ASP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284156/unable-to-reference-unc-paths-while-using-wscript-shell-from-an-asp-script/3337728#3337728)

Doing View Source of the kitty page, I see this:

```
<!--
Actual error:
The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D024)
-->
```

I'm using IE8, in case it matters, although looking at the error message I imagine it isn't a browser thing. The page is this revision: 2010.7.26.1

Known problem?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58545/cannot-update-a-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. The problem should be taken care of now.